# JAXB Class - XML not getting created as expected

Tags: fasterxml, jackson-modules

I am using fasterxml-jaxb(2.3) module to generate XML but it seems its not reading Xmlns annotation while creating XML. I have the prefix defined in my package-info as below

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "bla"....
```

Jackson does not apply the prefix however if i user I use JDK's JAXB for marshalling the prefix is applied to the XML

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does not use Package annotations for anything; so while JAXB annotations are supported (if using JAXB annotations module), no annotations are read from `package-info.java`.
This because Jackson annotation module is based on inheritance (you can add all annotations on super-classes, and they are visible for sub-types).

You may be able to add a mix-in annotation for super-class (or regular annotation), and that would work.